# How to block images in Firefox? (add-ons not working on certain websites)

Tags: firefox

I use a Firefox add-on called ImageBlock. It's usually excellent, but it doesn't work at all on Wikipedia or Amazon.com and when I right click an image at either of those websites I'm not given the option to add it to the block list. I installed SettingSanity and unchecked "load images" in Firefox Options but that didn't work either. What should I do to block images from there in Firefox?

Comment: You can block images from the Page Info dialog, under Permissions. It is on a site by site basis though. See [Mozilla Support - Page Info window](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/page-info-window-view-technical-details-about-page).

Answer (score 2):

There is a relevant bug ([1196784](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1196784)) that affects Firefox 38 thru 45. It might have been fixed in Firefox 48, scheduled for release in August 2016.

A possible workaround:
In about:config, toggle preference **dom.image.srcset.enabled** to false.
That will disable [srcset](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=870021), a new feature which allows web pages to provide different images for different screen resolutions. (Of course you would reset the pref to true when Firefox 48 arrives.) I verified the fix with Image Block on Wikipedia, using Firefox 45. No doubt there are sites and situations where this solution wouldn't be ideal though.

Update: Image Block 3.1 seems to work in spite of the Firefox bug.

Answer (score 0):

Go to about:config, search for this option "permissions.default.image" change to 1.

Possible values:

0 -- always load the images

1 -- never load the images

2 -- dont load third images

Reference: https://support.mozilla.org/zh-TW/questions/981640